# sort list Python

Tags: python, list

I have to sort this python list :

```
55.115783, 62.380159, 68.738354, 66.014074, 72.073756, 69.036055, 71.594129, 77.551457, 75.922748, 81.613726, 89.083050, 94.257211, 96.328673 ,102.489464, 111.449678, 118.870730
```

if I try to use list.sort() I obtain this :

```
102.489464, 111.449678, 118.870730, 55.115783, 62.380159, 66.014074, 68.738354, 69.036055, 71.594129, 72.073756, 75.922748, 77.551457, 81.613726, 89.083050, 94.257211, 96.328673
```

I really don't know why !! may somebody help me about !!

Comment: it would help if you gave us the actual "list" you were working with, however i can already see the issue. you have a list of strings! And they were being sorted lexically. Convert to list of floats before sorting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your values are being sorted as strings - `102` vs `5` will be sorted based on the first `1` in the string (and will thus be sorted in front of `5`) - and not the numeric value.

The easiest way to solve this is to use the `float` function together with `key` in the call to `sorted`:

```
>>> a = ['123', '6']
>>> sorted(a)
['123', '6']
>>> sorted(a, key=float)
['6', '123']
```

The `key` parameter takes a function that will be applied to each entry before determining the sort value, and this will give you a numeric value to sort by instead.

Comment: This is true if the required output is a list of strings. If the output required is a list of floats, a possible solution is `sorted(map(float, a))`

Comment: Yup. I'd suggest appliing it before sorting to be clearer about the intent in that case, since it'll explicitly state "we want to convert this list to a float list". This will require the user to be aware of possible shortcoming about a conversion to float, though - such as possibly not getting the same representation back as the original string represents.